# django update_or_create with multiple defaults / fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

I would like to use `update_or_create` to update several fields but I can't find the correct syntax. The following gives an error:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.instance, created = MyModel.objects.update_or_create(
        user=self.request.user, defaults=(
            {'field1': form.instance.field1},
            {'field2': form.instance.field2},
            {'field3': form.instance.field3},
        ))
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

The error I get is `'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'`.  I also tried this with a list, similar error.  It works fine when I have only one dictionary such as `defaults={'field1': form.instance.field1}`.  I'm assuming this should work with multiple dictionaries since the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) say that it helps avoid using `try` and `except` because "This pattern gets quite unwieldy as the number of fields in a model goes up."

Comment: All the defaults should be in a single dictionary, pass multiple fields at once in this dictionary to have multiple defaults

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't try that.  Hours...